# Codecademy FizzBuzz app works but is not accepted as answer

Tags: javascript, fizzbuzz

The instructions to write the app are:
01. Print out the numbers from 1 - 20.
02. The rules:
- For numbers divisible by 3, print out "Fizz".
- For numbers divisible by 5, print out "Buzz".
- For numbers divisible by both 3 and 5, print out "FizzBuzz" in the console.
- Otherwise, just print out the number.

And below is the JavaScript I wrote:

```
for (var i = 1; i <= 20; i++) {
    if (i % 3 === 0 && i % 5 === 0) {
        console.log("FizzBuzz");
    }
    if (i % 5 ===0) {
        console.log("Buzz");
    }
    else if (i % 3 === 0) {
        console.log("Fizz");
    }
    else { console.log(i);
    }
}
```

The above code prints (or logs to the console) the below results:

```
1
2
Fizz
4
Buzz
Fizz
7
8
Fizz
Buzz
11
Fizz
13
14
FizzBuzz
Buzz
16
17
Fizz
19
Buzz
```

However, even when it seems right to me, the message I get once I run the code is: "Oops, try again. It looks like you printed out the wrong number of items."

I know that I may be making a silly mistake, but I can't figure it out, I have spent enough time trying thing to no avail.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For 15, your output says FizzBuzz, and also Buzz. This is because in your code, you wrote an if statement to handle the divisibility by 5 case. Instead, you should use an else if as you did for the divisibility by 3 case. Your code should then look like:

```
for (var i = 1; i <= 20; i++) {
    if (i % 3 === 0 && i % 5 === 0) {
        console.log("FizzBuzz");
    }
    else if (i % 5 ===0) {
        console.log("Buzz");
    }
    else if (i % 3 === 0) {
        console.log("Fizz");
    }
    else { console.log(i);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need an else, because the other ifs gets evaluated, if no else is inserted

```
14
FizzBuzz   right (15)
Buzz       wrong (15)
16
```

Code:

```
if (i % 3 === 0 && i % 5 === 0) {
    console.log("FizzBuzz");
}
else if (i % 5 ===0) { // <------------------- insert else!
    console.log("Buzz");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Add `else` before

```
if (i % 5 ===0) {
```

to remove the wrong `Buzz` and remove the `else` before

```
console.log(i);
```

to always show the number (maybe that line should be the first).

The code should now be:

```
for (var i = 1; i <= 20; i++) {
    if (i % 3 === 0 && i % 5 === 0) {
        console.log("FizzBuzz");
    }
    else if (i % 5 ===0) {
        console.log("Buzz");
    }
    else if (i % 3 === 0) {
        console.log("Fizz");
    }
    console.log(i);
}
```